# Examples of mediums which are not linear, homogeneous and isotropic

Tags: electromagnetism, refraction

In electromagnetics we are taught that mediums can be linear/nonlinear,isotropic/anisotropic,homogeneous/non-homogeneous...we also learn their definitions. Now we are told that if nothing is specified then take the medium to be linear,homogeneous and isotropic. I want to know examples of those mediums which do not follow these criteria as I have never encountered such.

Comment: **Every** real medium is nonlinear, anisotropic and non-homogeneous.

Comment: ok so we have to work with approximations then..... but how to deal with permittivity,permeabilty or conductivity of anisotropic media which will come as tensors ?.....taking eigen values through diagonalization?

Comment: That is discussed thoroughly in any book on electromagnetism. Maybe you should wait until that is explained by your teacher, or grab a book on the subject.

Comment: I am an electrical engineering student and I have seen no text on engineering electromagnetics that deals this topic heavily...could you please name a few books or maybe give me some hints on which I can think?

Comment: Look up birefringent materials, like Iceland spar; or Land's polarizing film. Many crystaline materials are not isotropic - hence clevage planes. And yes, tensors are useful in studying these cases; usually in the upper level courses, perhaps senior level.

Comment: would you please give some reference ...a textbook or two ...after consulting with others..I might be ignorant but tremendously curious  :)......Thanks in advance

Comment: Look up "frequency multiplier crystals" for a very common application of anisotropic, nonlinear media. As for inhomogeneous, try graded-index optical fibers. Or just look up at the night sky and watch the stars twinkle.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that electromagnetism includes light waves.

- Any semi-transparent volumetric medium can have space-varying properties (transparency, colors) and thus be heterogeneous.
- Polarisers, and indeed many of gems, are not isotropic, because of the cristal network orientations.
- Various materials show some saturation or change of property at very high intensity (because there are not supra-conductors)

Moreover there exist 2 kinds of mediums: continuous medium, and composed medium. E.g. cloud/fog/smoke are made of very numerous and small objects floating in air. But

- These objects can have a non-symmetrical shape, and be consistantly oriented (e.g. ice cristal in some clouds, big non-spherical water droplet), causing anisotropy.
- There density (number per cubic meter) is very likely to varies (cloud/fog/smoke have borders :-) ).

Comment: these are all general information..useful though..I wanted something mathematical

Comment: Your question was " I want to know examples of those mediums which do not follow these criteria as I have never encountered such." What "mathematical" do you expect here, then ?

Comment: mathematically speaking, some constants won't be constant, and some k.laplacians(phi) are indeed div(k.grad(phi)) with k not a constant.

Comment: actually I  wanted to know about examples of non linear,non homogeneous,anisotropic media as well as their general analysis.....as for example in anisotropic media the medium properties like permittivity,permeability,etc are all tensors...we have been told.....n practical situations how people deal with tensors....hope you would get where I am trying to go

Comment: Well so what you actually want is a text book. It would be a bit too much to expect people here to build one just for you through these answers ;-)  . Or maybe narrow the question to something more specific.

Comment: ha ha I am not telling you guys to build it...I want some recommendation just...........a particular issue is do people diagonalize the tensor to get 3 eigen values....working with 9 entries ...you know  :)

Comment: well, I guess that in the most complex situations you just go with a matricial problem, i.e. a system of equations with more terms, and that's not so much a big deal. For the computer. Don't think of solving this by hand ! The only problems you solve by hand are those for which many parameters are simple. e.g. you might have anisotropy and everything else simple. Then, tell what you assume simple and what not and people will tell you for this very case how to factor out things.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding anisotropy, the common one is quartz. For quartz you commonly see ordinary/extraordinary rays refracted according to the two refractive indices of the two axes.

Silica optical fibres have a small nonlinearity. Because of symmetry, their even order nonlinearities go to zero but the third order nonlinearity exists and is used in soliton communication (where the nonlinearity counteracts the dispersion).

Nonlinear crystals are used in lasers for sum frequency generation. E.g. an Argon laser at 488 nm (blue) can be made to emit 244 nm in the UV with a properly aligned BBO crystal.

Nonlinearity is something we commonly experience in diodes, in this case the non-homogeneity of the doping creates a nonlinear response.

Comment: Quartz is also optically active.